# About the product and sum rules

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose we want to count single Pairs. One way to do that is

(pick a value)(choose $2$ suits to have that value)(pick the remaining $3$ values)(pick the suits for the remaining values).

My question has to do with why we use products here instead of sums.

Suppose I pick a value of $8.$ There are four of those and for each one of those we have four suits. This suggests multiplication. So I can see why we have the two products below:

(pick a value)(choose $2$ suits to have that value) **and** (pick the remaining $3$ values)(pick the suits for the remaining values). But why do we multiply these two products together? Sorry, having difficulty telling between product and sum rules.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. Your question is a good and understandable one, but your example doesn't make sense to me. Are we talking about playing cards? There are only $4$ 8's in a deck... one per suit...

Comment: @ The Count, yes I am assuming standard $52$ card deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each choice is dependent on the previous ones, then we have to calculate the sub-sums for each possible choice and then add together the sums for each possible choice.

If the count of the choices available is independent of the previous ones, then we can do the same, but the result is the same as multiplication.  So we take the short cut and multiply.

Either way the mental image of what we are doing is the same.  You build up a decision tree of all of the consequences of your choices, and you are trying to count the number of end results.

Comment: @ btilly, In what sense is picking two cards of one kind independent from picking three cards of different kinds? Thanks.

Comment: @shaniqua For every pair that you pick in the first step, there are an equal number of choices that you can make in the second one.  The actual choices that you make will be different - you can't use the values already picked - but the number is the same.  As long as the number is the same, you can multiply.

Comment: @ btilly, if I already have a pair of Aces, shouldn't that affect my choice of other 3 cards (I won't be able to choose Aces) implying some sort of dependence?

Comment: @ btilly, I see what's up. If we take the sum of elements in two sets one of which contains the pairs and the other contains the triples, we'll just end up with a set of disjoint pairs and triples. We need a set of 5-tuples.

Comment: @shaniqua I tried clarifying my wording slightly.  You get different actual choices with aces vs twos, but the *count* of choices is the same.  Adding the same count many times gives you multiplication.